# Get bq cancel to cancel running bq job

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm currently facing a weird issue where the `bq cancel` command refuses to cancel a job that is returned by the `bq ls -j` command (STATUS = RUNNING).

The job is running and prevents me from updating a table.

While the reasons behind the running job not being able to complete are still not clear, I'd like to be able to at least finish the job and start a new one.

Has anyone already face this issue?

I listed the jobs and found one that is running using the `bq ls -j` command.

I tried to cancel it (even though there is no reason for this job not to work) and I'm being returned `BigQuery error in cancel operation: Not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try these methods described in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#cancel_a_job)? There are several ways to cancel a job. Can you try adding location flag such as this example?:

> bq --location=LOCATION cancel JOB_ID

If this job still persist even after methods mentioned above, I would suggest creating a support case for this inquiry to let support to peek in to the job/ logs  or API resources that causing the stucked and uncancellable job. Possibly you can request to cancel the job within the case.

https://cloud.google.com/contact

Comment: OK thank you so much, it works when adding the --location flag. It's weird but it it works, it works